# Запись в файл с новой строки

Tags: файлы, php

Скажите, пожалуйста, скрипт для записи в файл с новой строки есть файл "file.txt" и текстовое поле "info".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $_POST['info'] . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: В РНР есть константа **PHP_EOL** для обозначения конца строки

Comment: @dekameron Есть но если скрипт работает на linux сервере у него "\n" и если читать фаил на виндовс там необходим "\r\n"

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте, [@cas-live](/users/5977/cas-live).
Добавьте к концу каждой добавляемой строке **\r\n**

Answer (score 1):

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a+'); - а+ добавляет новые данные после существующих
fwrite($fp, $_POST['info']."\r\n"); а "r\n\" - вставляет их каждый рас с новой строки
fclose($fp);
```

Вот так должно выглядеть!

> Цитата
>
> Я это так реализовал
> код действующий

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['dosave'])){
  $res=$_POST['res'];
  $filt = $_POST['file']; 
  $filo = $_POST['filo']; 
  $fito = $_POST['fito'];
  $fino = $_POST['fino'];
  $fitto = $_POST['fitto'];
} 
?>
<?php 
    echo    $fino;
?>

<?php   
    echo    $filt, $fitto;
?>

<?php   
    echo    $fito;
?>

<?php   
    echo    $filo;
?>

<?php   
    echo date ( ' j F Y ' ) ; 
?>

<?php
$opis = $fino. ' ' .$filt. ' ' .$fitto. ' ' .$fito. ' ' .$filo;
$s = fopen("file.txt","a+");
fwrite($s,$opis."\r\n");
fclose($s);
?>
```

Comment: каждый раз передовая данные с формы 
они заносятся в новую строку.
И при этом все данные с формы объеденены в одну строку.

Comment: Задача решена, но спасибо